# Using a custom font for a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel

I'm trying to use a special font in my JFrame, but I'm running into problems. I have a JLabel defined like this:

```
private JLabel lab = new JLabel("Text");
```

and I have a file called CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF (TrueType font) but after writing the following:

```
    try {
    lab.setFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResource("/CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF").openStream()));
    } catch(IOException ex){
    //exception handled here I suppose  
    } catch(FontFormatException ex2) {
    //same here
    }
```

the code compiles and the everything works right except that "lab" is not displayed so there is no text. I suppose it is because I never specified what the font size should be, but any attempt I have made to do that fails. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Font you created has to be registered first in the `GraphicsEnvironment` to be accessible to all and derive the size of the font:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResource("/CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF").openStream());   

GraphicsEnvironment genv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
genv.registerFont(font);
// makesure to derive the size
font = font.deriveFont(12f);
```

Comment: Okay I would like to this differently then, is there another method? I wanted to just use lab.setFont() but I needed to decide on the font style (even though the TrueType file is set at medium) and I got an error if I type something like Font.PLAIN.

Comment: *"The Font you created has to be registered first in the GraphicsEnvironment"* - I don't need to register it, but you are right on the other count.  When created, a new `Font` has a size of `1` you need to derive a new size...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Maybe you can help? What I would like to do is something like this: Font f = new Font(getClass().getResource("/CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF"),{style},17) followed by lab.setFont(f) but I don't know what goes instead of {style} and reading the documentation does not help.

Comment: @sid `font = font.deriveFont(12f);` is the key you are looking for.  I've added an example showing what I mean, but @sasankad is correct and deserves the credit for answering first

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Yes you are correct, registering font in the GraphicsEnvironment is not a must.

Comment: (ps - While not required, `registerFont` is not incorrect nor ill-advisable, depending on what you want to do)

Comment: The problem is solved and I'm marking this answer as the "accepted answer" as suggested. Users who find this thread later on Google or something might benefit from reading the answer by @MadProgrammer below as well.

Answer (score 10):

@sasankad is mostly correct (+1).

Once you have created the font, it will have a default size of `1`

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF"));
```

You then need to derive the font size and style you want.

```
Font biggerFont = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48f);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCustomFont {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCustomFont();
    }

    public TestCustomFont() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            try {
                Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Royal Chicken.ttf"));
                JLabel happy = new JLabel("Happy little Miss Chicken");
                happy.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48f));
                add(happy);
            } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Check out [java.awt.Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) for more details...

You may also want to take a look at [Physical and Logical Fonts, Font Configuration Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html#font-configuration-files)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The line: font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getAsStream("/CUSTOMFONT-MEDIUM.TTF")) won't complile: "The method "getAsStream(String)" is undefined for the type Class<capture#17 [...]" Do you understand what the problem is here?

Comment: @FaithReaper That's pretty much what it says, just the first instance you get is sized to `1`, you need to derive a new size from it. Most modern fonts aren't pixel based and so are resizable to about any size you want

Comment: Another useful point, is that even if the register is not alway necessary, you can register one particular size, and all sizes are available when you use it, if the font file contains the size you want to use. You can register `48f` and use size `14`, and viceversa. It applies to style, too. May be convenient if you want to use different style and font size.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I agree. And the style, too, and about that I don't quite understand. It's because the file contains the style? Another thing is, if you only derive once you get one font, but if you register the font you get all the file contains. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @FaithReaper Not really, a true type font doesn't have a "size" associated with, it's a vector based algorithm which allows it to scale to whatever size you want, so, technically, you're not registering sizes at all, you just registering the formula need to scale it. The same goes for opentype and post script fonts

Comment: @FaithReaper No, when you register the font, basically you're making it available to the JVM to find and load it.  When you derive a font, you're taking the current properties of a font object (including size and style) and applying new properties to it, it's just a simpler way to interact with an instance of a `Font` object. Styling can be applied mathematically if it's not provided by the font itself, but many font's do have additional styling descriptors

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense to me, so the style and font size are properties added to the Font when we derive, not because it's present beforehand. Thanks for the explanation. So even if I don't register, I can use different size and style than that I derive, if I want to?

Comment: @FaithReaper Unless the font is installed on the system, you MUST register first before you can use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137739/discussion-between-faithreaper-and-madprogrammer).