# How to use font from Google Fonts in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane, google-fonts

I was previously working on web and there for using a Google Font I can simple add the link for that and use it in CSS. Now I'm working in `javax.swing`. I want to use a Google Font which I selected in JTextPane. I have downloaded the font and how do I set the font to the downloaded font?

Comment: Does this help? [Adding fonts to Swing application and include in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998604/adding-fonts-to-swing-application-and-include-in-package)

Comment: Using custom fonts, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing/24177458#24177458); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081586/using-a-custom-font-for-a-jlabel/21081821#21081821); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278648/how-to-change-font-in-java-gui-application/24278825#24278825). But I suspect getting it to actually work with `JTextPane` might be a little more involved

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jtextpane+custom+font&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) has a number of possible useful examples as well