# How can I do a custom font style in a label in java?

Tags: java, fonts

I'm trying to create a custom font in java and add this font to a `Jlabel`, but I get an error in the second line at `createFont`.

Here's What I did:

```java
JLabel Title = new JLabel("Text");
Font fnt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("pixelFont.TTF"));
Title.setFont(fnt);
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Since [`createFont`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,java.io.File)) can throw an [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) or a [`FontFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/FontFormatException.html) I assume you're getting one of those, unless you just aren't catching or declaring the exception as thrown and your code isn't compiling, but there's no way to know unless you tell us.

Comment: Try looking at [Using a custom font for a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081586/using-a-custom-font-for-a-jlabel).

Answer (score 0):

Thank for everyone's replies, what happened was that I forgot to add a try/catch block:

```
    try {
        Font fnt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Hauptsächlich.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pixelFont.TTF"));
        Title.setFont(fnt.deriveFont(Font.BOLD,47f));
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Plus I used the `new File("pixelFont.TTF")` instead of:

`<The name of the class>.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pixelFont.TTF")`

Which also means that even if I could run the code without any errors, it still wouldn't do what I needed it to do, and that was basically it. Now the code runs without any problems, and my JLabel is now in a custom font.

p.s: I'm still kind of new to the entire process of writing projects, but I'm learning as quick as possible. ;)